# Trying to update an Android SDK but Getting some issues

Tags: java, android

in eclipse installation details the version takes 23.0.4 but i try to update the SDK it shows 24.0.2 so their is a confliction between 23 and 24 , in sdk thier is a rev 22 and direct shows update available rev 24.0.2, here is am posting the screenshots

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the issue

Comment: i want to update my sdk from 22 to 23, but 23 is not available as you can see in 2nd image, so how can i update sdk to 23

Comment: You don't want to update to 23, there is a v24, which is newer and better than 24 so use that

Comment: if i will update it 24 than unable i am unable to open SDK Manager from eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution: I have find the solution for that, install "Android Studio 1.0.1" from developers site "http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html". It should automatically install 24.0.2.

1) There was a bug in SDK Tools 24.0.0 which makes the SDK Manager not work on some 32-bit Windows systems. When you start Android Studio 1.0.1 you get a balloon saying that Tools 24.0.1 is available; click on it, and then you can install it right from within the IDE (that doesn't use the SDK Manager to do the install). SDK Manager should now work again. If not you can download a fix for the SDK manager directly from 
http://tools.android.com/knownissues

2) I also met this issue after updated Android SDK Tools, the find_java.bat file in your SDK Dir\tools\lib PATH has a small problem.

Please replace the code in line33: %sys_32%\find /i "x86" > NUL && set arch_ext=32 || set arch_ext=64 to %sys_32%\find /i "x86" > NUL && (set arch_ext=32) || (set arch_ext=64) and save it. Restart android.bat in your SDK Dir\tools PATH. It will run normally!!!

BTW, the newest Android SDK Tools(24.0.2) has repaired this issue!